# Type assertion on Goa package (uuid.UUID)

Tags: regex, go

I'm testing out [Goa](https://github.com/goadesign/goa) for an API.  I want to use uuid as an ID data type.  I modified the following function in controller.go:

```
// Show runs the show action.
func (c *PersonnelController) Show(ctx *app.ShowPersonnelContext) error {
    // v4 UUID validate regex
    var validate = `^[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-4[a-f0-9]{3}-[8|9|aA|bB][a-f0-9]{3}-[a-f0-9]{12}$`
    uuidValidator := regexp.MustCompile(validate)
    if !uuidValidator.Match(ctx.MemberID) {
        return ctx.NotFound()
    }
    // Build the resource using the generated data structure
    personnel := app.GoaCrewWorkforce{
        MemberID:  ctx.MemberID,
        FirstName: fmt.Sprintf("First-Name #%s", ctx.MemberID),
        LastName:  fmt.Sprintf("Last-Name #%s", ctx.MemberID),
    }
```

What I would like to do is validate a v4 uuid in my controller using Regexp so that it does not poll the server if it does not validate. It's my understanding a uuid is a [16]byte slice.  Regexp has a  `Match` []byte function.  Yet I can't seem to understand why I get the following error:

```
cannot use ctx.MemberID (type uuid.UUID) as type []byte in argument to uuidValidator.Match
```

How can I type assert ctx.MemberID?  I don't think its possible to do a cast conversion in this case?  Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What uuid package are you using? The 16 bytes of uuid data aren't going to match that string format. Also, if you know the type is a uuid.UUID, then why try to validate again if it's a uuid?

Comment: @JimB Goa seems to have their own uuid implementation.  Moreover, their package imports github.com/satori/go.uuid.  You make a valid point about the validation, what I want is basically to make sure a valid uuid is existent in the payload before the request is sent.  Is this logic the wrong way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate the uuid, you can check the bits directly. There's not much to verify, since most of the 16 bytes are random, but you can check the top 4 bits of the 6th byte for the version number, or the top 3 bits of the 8th byte for the variant.

```
// enforce only V4 uuids
if ctx.MemberID[6] >> 4 != 4 {
    log.Fatal("not a V4 UUID")
}

// enforce only RFC4122 type UUIDS
if (ctx.MemberID[8]&0xc0)|0x80 != 0x80 {
    log.Fatal("not an RFC4122 UUID")
}
```

Comment: ctx.MemberID is of type github.com/goadesign/goa/uuid and not github.com/satori/go.uuid so the RFC variant and version are undefined.

Comment: @Alex, (sorry, realized my connection failed, and the doc page was still on satori/go.uuid). The functions from the satori/go.uuid package are small and easy to copy. There's not a lot of benefit to checking though, since for the purpose of a unique identifier, checking that almost 16 bytes of random data have a couple non-random bits doesn't gain much.